# Anchor doesn't follow scroll position and doesn't jump

Tags: reactjs, react-native, anchor, antd

Here is reproduction link https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-5lvmz

I've tried to follow https://ant.design/components/anchor but it doesn't work.
When I deleted

```
getContainer={() => document.querySelector("#my-scroll-layout")}
showInkInFixed={true} 
affix={true}
```

Anchor  follows scroll position but still it does't jump.

---

Bellow is a full code

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import { version} from "antd"
import "antd/dist/antd.css"
import "./index.css"
import Lorem from "./Lorem"
import { Anchor } from "antd"
const { Link } = Anchor

ReactDOM.render(
  <div className="App">
    <div>Current antd version: {version}</div>
    <Anchor
      getContainer={() => document.querySelector("#my-scroll-layout")}
      showInkInFixed={true}
      affix={true}
    >
      <Link href="#1" title="1" />
      <Link href="#2" title="2" />

      <Link href="#3" title="3" />
    </Anchor>
    <div id="my-scroll-layout">
      <h1 id="1">1</h1>
      <Lorem />
      <h1 id="2">2</h1>
      <Lorem />
      <h1 id="3">3</h1>
      <Lorem />
    </div>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define scroll and style for  the my-scroll-layout div.

https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-voopn

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate that. However, it still doesn't jump to necessary section once I click on the link. How could I fix that?

Comment: It will work, open  the answer sample in  new window: https://voopn.csb.app/
the problem in embedded  window of codesandbox behavior.

Comment: Thanks, Oleg! It works, I really appreciate your help and contribution!